# Where is DNS zone file in Centos 5 with Lxadmin?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, subdomain, zones

I would like to add A record for subdomain and am searching for a file with actual zone settings. Files /var/named/named.local and /var/named/localdomain.zone have only localhost settings and not my actual domain mydomain.com. So where is a zone settings file in default Centos 5 + Lxadmin configuration?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Bind uses a chroot based at `/var/named/chroot`. Have you tried looking in `/var/named/chroot/var/named`? Probably a file in that directory named mydomain.com.zone or mydomain.com.named.

Comment: in this folder (/var/named/chroot/var/named) i have only folders 'data' and 'slaves' and no files. data is empty (ls -a) and slaves also.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually running BIND? If so, the named.conf file, or one of it's included files, should tell you what and where the zone file is. If it's not listed then BIND is not handling that domain and you need to determine what is.

Answer (score 0):

debian puts things in `/var/cache/bind` as default (or atleast it seems to for me). Worth having a look.